# JPA Call Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

looking on the net I've found the annotation `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery`.

So in my Entity I've defined

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Ticket_TM")
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries(
        @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
                name = "getEmp",
                procedureName = "GET_EMP",
                returnsResultSet = false
        )

)
public class MyClass implements Serializable {...}
```

and in my service, I've defined

```
@Service
public class MyService implements IMyService
{
  @PersistenceContext EntityManager entityManager;

 @Override
 @Transactional
    public void callProcedure() 
    {
        StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("getEmp");
        query.execute();

        log.info("Procedure executed");
    }
}
```

But I get the error

```
No @NamedStoredProcedureQuery was found with that name : getEmp
```

Comment: `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery` is not JPA specific annotation. It's found in EclipseLink/TopLink specific JPA implementation.

Comment: Ah.. sorry.. so the only way to call pl/sql functions/procedure is with createNativeQuery ?

Comment: @NamedStoredProcedureQuery was included in JPA 2.1 actually. The annotation has package javax.persistence. Kindly define if you're using this annotation and with which JPA implementation

Comment: I'm using javax.persistence version 2.1.0. Could you help me then with the error i get? I've write something wrong ? I'm using Oracle with org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

Comment: Does your version of Hibernate support JPA 2.1? I have no problem using them with the implementation I use (DataNucleus v4) as per http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_0/jpa/stored_procedures.html   Is the entity listed in persistence.xml under "classes" ?

Comment: all was properly configured, maybe the error was in import. Now i've imported javax.persistence.NamedStoredProcedureQueries AND javax.persistence.NamedStoredProcedureQuery and all works. Maybe before i was imported hibernate Classes.